# show images from database in rdlc report

Tags: c#, rdlc

I am trying to show photo of each person associated with it in `rdlc` report. I tried using image and setting its source to database.

But, it is not working. I have stored image in `SQLite` database in `BLOB` format. How can I achieve that?

Comment: possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011015/rdlc-how-to-show-image-from-database

Answer (score 0):

1. In your *.rdlc [design] remove the textbox for the column you want to show the image and insert an **Image** control from the Toolbox.
2. When you drag the image to that the cell, the `Image Properties` dialog appears. Choose the `Database` for `Select the image source` and select the proper field and MIMe type.

Comment: yep bmp,jpeg,png,x-png and gif. None of them are showing any images. The I have the field with System.Byte[] as datatype.

Comment: system.byte[] is ok, the problem must be something else.

Comment: got it working. The problem was with the database field. I don't know what was the problem though, must be the field or the table itself.